# How can I write an avro schema for an array of arrays?

Tags: avro

For example, I've tried this one, but it isn't working. I have to create a schema that have in one field an arrays of arrays and I couldn't do it.

```
{
    "name": "SelfHealingStarter",
    "namespace": "SCP.Kafka.AvroSchemas",
    "doc": "Message with all the necessary information to run Self Healing process.",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "FiveMinutesAgoMeasurement",
            "type": "record",
            "doc": "Field with all five minutes ago measurement.",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "equipments",
                    "doc": "List with all equipments measurement.",
                    "type": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": "string"
                            },
                            "default": []
                        }
                    },
                    "default": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some information about the error you get and what you would like to get instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `"type": "record"` + `"fields"`, the `"type": "array"` and `"items"` go together within one object, such as

`"type": { "type": "array", "items": { ... } }`

Repeat into the innermost object.

For a simpler example - Here's the IDL definition of an array of arrays

```
protocol Example {
  record Foo {
    array<array<string>> data = [];
  }
}
```

AVSC from `java -jar ~/Downloads/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar idl2schemata example.idl`

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Foo",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "data",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : "string"
      }
    },
    "default" : [ ]
  } ]
}
```